Determine if a given time is between multiple time ranges
I'm trying to determine utlize a formula that will allow me to determine if a given time (TESTS "C2") is in between multiple time ranges (ATTEMPTS "B:C").
Using:
=IF(C2>=ATTEMPTS!$B$2,IF(C2<=ATTEMPTS!$C$2, "In Range", "Out of Range"), "Out of Range")

I can determine if Test #1 (TESTS "A2:D2") is in range of ATTEMPT #1 (ATTEMPTS "A2:D2") but need to run Test #1 against each ATTEMPT that corresponds with its ID number
ATTEMPTS

TESTS

I feel like this could be accomplished with some combination of INDEX and MATCH but I cant figure out a way to write that formula to accomplish my desired goal.
Thank you!

Pls. have a look Why not post code or data as image and Markdown help. How to format a Table

Pls. have a try to: =IF(SUM((C2>=ATTEMPTS!$B$2:$B$13)*(C2<=ATTEMPTS!$C$2:$C$13))>0, "In Range", "Out of Range")

Thank you! That works to determine if the test is during ANY of the attempts listed but I also need to match the attempts to the tests by ID number. So, I only need to know if Test #1 is during attempts A2:D6 (because they share the same ID number of '1')
and thank you, next time I will not post the data as an image. My apologies I am new to this forum!

Same logic as posted by @Blackcat : =IF(SUM((C2>=ATTEMPTS!$B$2:$B$13)*(C2<=ATTEMPTS!$C$2:$C$13)*(A2=ATTEMPTS!$A$2:$A$13))>0,"In Range","Out of Range") just add the id for boolean comparison

You can use the below formula if you want to implement that using dynamic arrays:
= LET( tests,             A2:D11,
       attempts,          A2:D13,
       attempts_ids,      INDEX(attempts,, 1),
       attempts_starts,   INDEX(attempts,, 2),
       attempts_ends,     INDEX(attempts,, 3),
       check_func,        LAMBDA( tests_row,
                                  LET( tests_ids,  INDEX(tests_row,, 1),
                                       tests_time, INDEX(tests_row,, 3),
                                       IF( SUM( (tests_time >= attempts_starts) *
                                                (tests_time <= attempts_ends) *
                                                (tests_ids = attempts_ids) ) > 0,
                                           "In Range",
                                           "Out Range")
                                     )),
       check_result,      BYROW(tests, check_func),
       check_result
     )

You just need to place it at E2 and then you can play around with the first two parameters (tables), tests and attempts, of the formula.
tests should be your TEST table range (A2:D11) and attempts should be your ATTEMPTS table range (A2:D13).
